# After TFS Database Restore, all functions stopped working

Tags: stored-procedures, tfs, sql-server-2008-r2

**after restoring TFS 2010 backup set**, all functionalities of TFS stopped working.

the error message is :

```
Procedure prc_security_read_identities
Must declare the scalar variable "@rowCount".
```

this error also occurs when executing **prc_security_read_identities** procedure manually. this is an encrypted stored procedure, so I can not see what is happening inside!

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure prc_security_read_identities, Line 77
Must declare the scalar variable "@rowCount".
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: I don't know what happened yet, but did you follow the backup/restore process for TFS databases on MSDN?

Comment: And have you tried DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear all the cached execution plans? Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: @Duat Le DBCC FREEPROCCACHE did not worked... :( also I restored backups using TFS Provided restore wizard

Comment: Things one could try: 1. prc_security_read_identities is the stored procedure which retrieves current users. What does the command "tfsconfig identities" say ? 2. Make sure the patch level is the same as before the database restore. 3. As a last resort the command: "tfsconfig repair"

Comment: I talked to a TFS dev about this and he inquired about the collation of the database and the SQL Server instance. Can you check and see what those are?